# Indent the block with the algorithm2e usepackage

Tags: algorithm2e

How can I indent the pseudocode block after this line `function Karatsuba(p,q)`?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{german,t1enc}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}

\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0.4pt}
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0.4pt}

%pseudocode.
\usepackage[linesnumbered,ruled,vlined]{algorithm2e} 

%Color
\usepackage[dvipsnames]{xcolor}
\renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{1.5}
%blacksquare
\usepackage{amssymb }
\begin{document}

\begin{algorithm}[H]
\SetAlgoLined
function Karatsuba(p,q) \\
  $n \leftarrow  degree(p) +1 $ \\
  \eIf{$n = 1$}{
   return $p.q$  
  }{
   $p(x) = p_1 * x^{\frac{n}{2}} + p_0$ \\
$ q(x) = q_1 * x^{\frac{n}{2}} + q_0$ \\
$p.q = p_1q_1.(x)^n + ( (p_0+p_1)(q_0+q_1) - p_0q_0 - p_1q_1). (x)^\frac{^n}{2} + p_0q_0$
  }

\caption{}
\label{alg: initializer}
\end{algorithm}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

One way is to use the [`algorithm2e`](https://mirror.ox.ac.uk/sites/ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/algorithm2e/doc/algorithm2e.pdf) command `\SetKwBlock{}{}{}` (section 11.2 of the CTAN manual) like this:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[linesnumbered,ruled,vlined]{algorithm2e} 
\renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{1.5}

\begin{document}

\begin{algorithm}[H]
\SetKwBlock{Func}{function Karatsuba(p,q)}{}
\SetAlgoLined
\Func{
  $n \leftarrow  degree(p) +1 $ \\
  \eIf{$n = 1$}{
   return $p.q$  
  }{
   $p(x) = p_1 * x^{\frac{n}{2}} + p_0$ \\
$ q(x) = q_1 * x^{\frac{n}{2}} + q_0$ \\
$p.q = p_1q_1.(x)^n + ( (p_0+p_1)(q_0+q_1) - p_0q_0 - p_1q_1). (x)^\frac{^n}{2} + p_0q_0$
  }
}
\caption{}
\label{alg: initializer}
\end{algorithm}
\end{document}
```

which produces this:

[image]